# Write in all the *.txt files within a directory using Python

Tags: python

I want to write in all the files within a directory based on their extensions. I can write to a specific file but my goal is code that can write to all the `*.txt` files that are in a specific directory. With the following code I can list all text files and search for a file but as a beginner in Python I don't know how to write a sentence in all the `*.txt` files.

```
import glob
import os
directory=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\z')

myfiles=glob.glob('*.txt')
print(myfiles)



def find_files(filename, search_path):
    result= []

    for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
        if filename in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            return result


print(find_files("zineb.txt",r"C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\z"))
```

Comment: It's a good start. I'll give you a hint: to be able to write and read from a file you need to use the `open` function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open here you have the documentation for it. There are examples too. You can do it!

Answer (score 0):

In your example you should be able to just do the following:

```
textfiles = find_files("zineb.txt",r"C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\z")
for textfile in textfiles: # go over each file that it found
    with open(textfile, "a") as f: # open the textfile in mode append (hence the a) and have it be assigned to f
        f.write("a") # then write "a" to the file.
```

To do all of them:

```
for textfile in os.listdir():
    if textfile.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(textfile, "a") as f:
            f.write("a")
```

Comment: with that i can write only in zineb.txt but i want to write in all files in that directory

Comment: No problem dude; if it helped then you should tick he arrow underneath the arrows on my answer so that people know when they are looking, :)